# GAE development server keep full text search indexes after restart?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-search

Is there anyway of forcing the GAE dev server to keep full text search indexes after restart? I am finding that the index is lost whenever the dev server is restarted.

I am already using a static datastore path when I launch the dev server (the `--datastore_path` option).

Comment: the same happens to me. i made a convenience handler/method to reindex all entities when this happens.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality was added a few releases ago (in either 1.7.1 or 1.7.2, I think). If you're using an SDK from the last few months it should be working. You can try explicitly setting the `--search_indexes_path` flag on `dev_appserver.py`; it's possible that the default location (`/tmp/`) isn't writable. Could you post the first few lines of the logs from when you start dev_appserver?

Comment: I tried using the `--search_indexes_path` flag and it didn't work. The relevant line from the log would be: `WARNING  2012-12-17 13:36:04,474 simple_search_stub.py:950] Could not read search indexes from C:\CBFW2_DATA\LOCAL.searchindexes` (this was after I put some data in the search index, stopped and then restarted the dev server). I am running SDK 1.7.3.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Could you post the full command you're using to start dev_appserver? Are there any lines in the logs when you stop the dev server that mention search?

Comment: Here is the full set of options that I'm using to start dev_appserver.py: `--debug --datastore_path=C:\CBFW2_DATA\LOCAL.datastore --default_partition="" --address=localhost --use_sqlite --search_indexes_path=C:\CBFW2_DATA\LOCAL.searchindexes`.

Comment: Here's an entry in the log that might point to the problem: `ERROR    2012-12-19 09:42:54,936 warnings.py:133] C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\search.py:3205: DeprecationWarning: consistency is deprecated. GLOBALLY_CONSISTENT is no longer supported. spec_pb.set_consistency(_CONSISTENCY_MODES_TO_PB_MAP.get(index.consistency)`.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, I'm not setting up my index as globally consistent. Here is the code I'm using to add documents: `search.Index(name=self._INDEX_NAME).put(document_to_index)`

Comment: That warning is a known issue, and is fixed in 1.7.4. This sounds like a bug. Could you open a bug on the bug tracker (http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) and paste the link here, and I'll follow up?

Comment: I opened a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8577&q=full%20text%20search&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone else comes looking for this, it looks like the simple solution is now to specify

```
--storage_path=/not/the/tmp/dir
```

you can still override this with --datastore_path etc.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver
(at the bottom of the page..)

Answer (score -2):

Look like this is not an issue anymore. according to documentation (and my tests):

> "The development web server simulates the App Engine datastore using a
>   file on your computer. This file persists between invocations of the
>   web server, so data you store will still be available the next time
>   you run the web server."

Please let me know if it is otherwise and I will follow up on that.