# GAE Full text search data is cleared on dev server restart

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

I am using GAE local server for development. I am storing in datastore as well as Full text search to do some specific search. When I restart my local dev server the data in datastore is retained where as the Full text search indexes get cleared. This results in an inconsistent data in my application. Is it possible to retain index data in Full Text search ?

Comment: change the location of the file used to store the db from /tmp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is my local App Engine datastore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588817/where-is-my-local-app-engine-datastore)

Comment: I tried this. Full Text Search is still cleared on server restart

Comment: hmm, this rings a bell now. Try finding the file itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801095/how-do-i-find-all-the-files-that-were-created-today-in-unix-linux as a starting point

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843907/gae-development-server-keep-full-text-search-indexes-after-restart maybe? I know this is for indexes, but could it be that the data is stored at a similar place or can be kept in a similar way?

Comment: have you set --storage_path= https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver

Comment: I tried --storage_path, its then looking for a file <storage_path>/search_indexes.

Comment: I tried --search_indexes_path. Its the same error as in the link. The bug that was raised as part of the discussion has been closed as fixed.

Comment: @bala if it's been fixed, there's a good chance that it will be part of the newest SDK release, no? Wait for 1.9.19?

Comment: @Patrice apparently it was closed in Dec 2013. So if there had been a fix it should already be available.

Comment: @bala then try and reopen the issue? well... I mean open a new one and link to the closed one, saying it's not fixed?

Comment: @Patrice I have created another one at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11749&thanks=11749&ts=1425533802. Lets see what the response is.

Answer (score 0):

Similar think happen to me (local server only), looks like the 'put_async' didn't work for me:

> search.Index(name='myindex').put_async(search.Document(...))

When I used 'put' the documents got stored:

> id = search.Index(name='myindex').put(search.Document(...))

The second problem I had was, that I was running the appengine from eclipse, and when you terminate the app engine in eclipse, it will not save the search_indexes file! To overcome this problem, I found out you can run the app engine with pydev debugger which will output process pid in console (use the first one) and then you can just sent

> kill -SIGINT [the pid from console]

which is like ctrl-c. The appengine server will handle the signal and save search_indexes.

The output looks like this on start:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 7643)
INFO     2015-12-10 06:02:42,308 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2015-12-10 06:02:42,527 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2015-12-10 06:02:42,852 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:45081
INFO     2015-12-10 06:02:43,037 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-12-10 06:02:43,041 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 7664)
INFO     2015-12-10 06:02:50,740 module.py:787] default: "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 404 27
```

after sending kill -SIGINT 7643

```
INFO     2015-12-10 06:21:19,494 shutdown.py:45] Shutting down..
INFO     2015-12-10 06:21:19,546 api_server.py:648] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2015-12-10 06:21:19,561 api_server.py:651] Saving search indexes
```